# asp.net TextBox select only certain text

Tags: asp.net, textbox, webforms

I want to select a certain area of a TextBox control in asp.net WebForms application.
The situation is that the textbox contains email addresses seperated by `;`. I wrote a little MailValidator class that sorts out valid and invalid email addresses.

Now i want the wrong email address to be selected, so that the user can correct it right away.
As i mentioned, I know which addresses are valid and which aren't.

How do I do that?
I know how to select the whole text with `.Focus()` **(works at least in IE, and that's enough)**
But how can I only select a certain area?
Is `TextBox.Text.Select<>` the way to go? If so, can someone provide an example? 
I don't fully understand what `.Select<>` actually does.

Comment: `TextBox.Text.Select<>` is not for selecting perticular text inside a textbox. `.Select<>` is a projection operator that can be applied to any list or array. Since `TextBox.Text` returns a `String` i.e. a array of `char` type, so you are seeing `Select<>` in VS intellisence. It has nothing to do with selecting textbox data. So don't be cofused with that!

Comment: Thanks. I already suspected that .Select<> has nothing to do with text selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use **Javascript** with this function, you just need to find the start and end of your selection.

```
function createSelection(field, start, end) {
    if( field.createTextRange ) {
      var selRange = field.createTextRange();
      selRange.collapse(true);
      selRange.moveStart('character', start);
      selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
      selRange.select();
      field.focus();
    } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
      field.focus();
      field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if( typeof field.selectionStart != 'undefined' ) {
      field.selectionStart = start;
      field.selectionEnd = end;
      field.focus();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Allright, so it's not possible with c#. Now I just have to figure out how to access javascript in asp.net (Yes, I am quite new to asp.net :) ) But I am sure that I will get there. Thanks for the Answer! I will report back later.

Comment: would that be something along the line:
`<asp:TextBox ID="txtAdditionalEmail" runat="server" TabIndex="130" Width="264px" CssClass="Feld2" onFocus="createSelection(frmTelefonzettel.txtAdditionalEmail.Text, 1, 5)" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Discregard this comment. The keyword 'this' was enough to tell the function which field i wanted to use. Thanks you very much for your help!! Question marked as answered.